# Android - How to stop starting service interval while service on running?

Tags: android, service

I have a service class called myService and I using interval to running the service

here's the code :

```
public class myService extends Service {
    public Runnable mRunnable = null;
    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public myService getServerInstance() {
            return myService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Service jalan", "beneran dah");
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                for (Contact cn : contacts)
                {
                    int idsql = cn.getID();
                    if(String.valueOf(cn.getFlag()).equals("0")){
                        Log.d("Id", String.valueOf(cn.getID()) + " Flag :" + cn.getFlag());
                        sending a  = new sending(); //communicate to server
                        a.execute();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("Data kosong", "atau tidak ada flag = 0");
                    }
                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30 * 1000);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30 * 1000);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

the issue :

when my service still running on `if statement` but the interval already loop for 30 sec, my service will be start again,

how can I avoid that?

Comment: another idea please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to check whether service is in progress before restarting it as in

```
 boolean isInProgress = false;
 mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Service jalan", "beneran dah");
                if(!isInProgress){
                isInProgress = true;
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                for (Contact cn : contacts)
                {
                    int idsql = cn.getID();
                    if(String.valueOf(cn.getFlag()).equals("0")){
                        Log.d("Id", String.valueOf(cn.getID()) + " Flag :" + cn.getFlag());
                        sending a  = new sending(); //communicate to server
                        a.execute();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("Data kosong", "atau tidak ada flag = 0");
                    }
                  }
                 isInProgress = false;
               }
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30 * 1000);
            }
```

Comment: i've a warning that `isInProgress always true`, when im simplify that, it back to my code without `if(!isInProgress){`